# How to get only the first row from a ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How do I get only the first row from a `ResultSet`? I know how to iterate through the entire set, but how do I get just the first row?

Comment: just do not iterate. remove iteration loop. Better to improve your query to return 1 row if you do not need all rows

Comment: Just add a LIMIT to the query?

Answer (score 53):

Instead of iterating over the result set, just check if there exists an entry an read it:

```
ResultSet r = ...;
if(r.next()) {
  String s = r.getString(1);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the following approach works well:

```
ResultSet RSet  = ...;
RSet.next();
Integer TestType = RSet.getInt("Type");
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `resultSet.next();` simply extract the data,

> A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.

Alternatively You can also call [`first()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first%28%29)

> Moves the cursor to the first row in this ResultSet object.

---

- [ResultSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: You can't just omit the call to `ResultSet.next().` By default it is located before the first row. `ResultSet.first()` is not an 'alternative'.

Comment: @EJP why not ? <!--->

Comment: @user207421 is correct - you can't call .first()   In later versions of the MySQL driver this will cause ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY errors. 

.next() works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `absolute` to navigate to the first row:

```
ResultSet rs = ...;
rs.absolute(1); // Navigate to first row
int id = rs.getInt("id");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Code to get first row or first field of multiple rows
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
//Establish connection
con = DriverManager.getConnection(sConnString, sUserName, sPassword);
//Create statement.
statement = con.createStatement();
sQueryToExecute = "select field_Name from Table_Name where condition order by desc";
System.out.println(sQueryToExecute);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sQueryToExecute);
while(rs.next())
{
    stringToStoreValue = rs.getString(1);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who seek an answer for Sqlite - Android, Here is my approach.

```
 if(RS.moveToNext()){
     String s = RS.getString(1);
     ... 
 }
```