# PMD: Avoid using a branching statement as the last in a loop

Tags: java, while-loop, pmd, coding-style

I'm playing with PMD a little bit. It says "Avoid using a branching statement as the last in a loop.".

```
    private static MyClass getObj(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        while (rs.next()) {
            MyClass obj = new MyClass(rs.getString("name"));

            // do other stuff

            return obj;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logAndShowException(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

How would you fix this warning?

I thought about removing the while loop and just wrote an if-statement because I'm expecting exactly one ResultSet.

Thanks.

Comment: On which line do you get the warning?

Comment: please dont declare objects inside the loop

Comment: @Selva It doesn't really matter when it's not actually a loop - it's guaranteed to never execute twice. Overall a loop is just the wrong thing to use there like Thiago said in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop is definitely not necessary, since you will exit right away no matter what. Your suggestion to use an `if` statement is good and you should proceed with it. You'll get rid of the PMD violation and your code will make more sense.

Check [How to get only the first row from a ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800721/how-to-get-first-row-from-resultset-from-query) and have fun with PMD.