# Get specific row in ResultSet?

Tags: java, sql, resultset, jtds

After getting results from a SQL query, I can access the results via a while loop :

```
String query = "SELECT TAX_RATE_ID FROM dbo.TAX_RATE where zip_code = 38401";
ResultSet rs= conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("TAX_RATE_ID"));
}
```

But I don't want to access them in a while loop, I want to just get the single result and return the value, since I know what to expect when the query is ran.  So I tried this:

```
String query = "SELECT TAX_RATE_ID FROM dbo.TAX_RATE where zip_code = 38401";
ResultSet rs= conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
rs.first();
System.out.println(rs.getString("TAX_RATE_ID"));
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet may only be accessed in a forward direction.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.checkScrollable(JtdsResultSet.java:319)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.first(JtdsResultSet.java:545)
    at com.kirklands.automation.ecom.Testing.main(Testing.java:12)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only the first row from a ResultSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800721/how-to-get-only-the-first-row-from-a-resultset)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to call `next()` in a loop. If you just want to get the first row, use:

```
String query = "SELECT TAX_RATE_ID FROM dbo.TAX_RATE where zip_code = 38401";
ResultSet rs= conn.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("TAX_RATE_ID"));
}
```

---

Unrelated, but:

`conn.createStatement().executeQuery()` will create a `Statement` instance that you can't clean up properly using `close()`.

Comment: Or make it scrollable, I guess. But your solution is the easiest by far.

Comment: OK, thanks. So what would be a good alternative to `conn.createStatement().executeQuery()`?

Comment: Use prepared statement instead, that works like charm.                  
 preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);